# Yahoo UI Tabview with embedded SWF

Tags: flash, yui

I have a flash app embedded in a yui TabView tab div, the problem is that each time I click the tab with the flash app, the flash app reloads.

Does anyone have any information on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look @ http://asv3.wordpress.com/2009/10/28/yui-tab-and-flash-graphmovie/

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it will help.